# Where should I implement the code in jTable (Drag and Drop)?

Tags: java, swing

I used a jTable from Swing Controls in my program(Drag and Drop). I want to know if there is any tutorials for jTables so that I can learn how to code for jTable. I saw many coding examples but couldn't identify where I should implement.

For example when I need to change a cell value after initializing, I don't know the place where I should implement the code.

Can anyone give me an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't just help: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea to go through Oracle Documentation at:
[How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Welcome! I hope it will help you.